# Gulp Script [Gulp Watch] - Cannot find module 'browser-sync'

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, browser-sync, gulp-watch

So I know there's other instances of this error but no matter what other way I've tried I continue getting this error

```
 throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'browser-sync'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\shiha\Desktop\coding\html\myWebsite\gulpfile.js:3:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
```

I have tried cleaning the cache and recalling npm install
as well as npm i broswer-sync --save. Nothing changes.

Here's a copy of my gulp script but I don't believe I'm doing anything wrong in that.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: 'app'
    },
  })
})

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
    }))
});

gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync', 'sass'], function (){
  gulp.watch('app/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
  // Reloads the browser whenever HTML or JS files change
  gulp.watch('app/*.html', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);
});
```

Im on a windows machine 
npm -v = 5.6
node -v = 7.4

Thanks in advance im just stuck.
Also here's a copy of my json because at first I thought I was missing the package but I have it installed already. And when I recall npm install I just get "up to date"

```
  "devDependencies": {
   "browser-sync": "^2.21.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems the package is missing, just do an npm install.

**`npm install browser-sync --save`**

Comment: I was just about to edit my question to add in my json but I already have it installed.

Comment: I get an npm error now which is saying                                                                      "npm ERR! 404 Not Found: broswer-sync@latest"

Comment: run this now npm install browser-sync gulp --save-dev

Comment: doing that adds it back into the devDependencies on the json so I went and ran "gulp watch" but that just brings back the original error seen in my post.

Comment: run npm cache clean

Comment: Ok I have that done but I had to add the --force tag to get it to go through

Comment: what happens now

Comment: this is strange !

Comment: I know this never happened before on any other packages usually a basic uninstall/reinstall would fix things.

Comment: What I am trying now is to take the windows bash instead of cmd to install the packages.

Comment: I believe I found a roundabout way of fixing this @Sajeetharan. I believe this is a windows problem because when I instead go on windows bash the ubuntu based terminal and now do a cache clean and npm install the gulp script now works.

Answer (score 0):

I can't fully confirm that this is a windows problem but a roundabout way of solving this problem that I found was to use windows bash terminal instead of cmd or PowerShell. Doing this just call

```
npm install
```

and this should now install all the necessary packages but for a Linux environment. Now if you call your gulp script in cmd it won't work but if you do so in the windows bash terminal it will.